# How to change the font-size using CKEDITOR.instances and execCommand?

Tags: css, angularjs, font-size, ckeditor4.x, execcommand

I am using CK Editor's execCommand() for '**bold**, *italic*, underline, etc' like-

```
var editorInstance = CKEDITOR.instances[fooBar]; //It returns each instance as object
editor.execCommand('italic');
```

I want to change the font-size of the text. How can i do that ?

Comment: you can simply write your own. http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.command

Comment: I found a way to do it, but not by using execCommand but instead using ckeditor's property **applyStyle(style)**

Comment: you need to create your own command, then you need "register" using addCommand and then you can use it with execCommand

Comment: see http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#addCommand

Comment: also see Full Source Code, you can see how to use addCommand http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me.